# Problem with block override in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, class, override-block

**Note: Before marking the question as duplicate or off-topic, please read the question carefully.**

**Scenario:**
I have to show custom column in the admin grid of a custom extension. So I used override feature of Magento 2 and extended the original Grid class to customize it.

Below is sample code block for overriding the Grid.php class:

```
namespace Stream\OverrideStockMovement\Block;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column;

class Grid extends \BoostMyShop\AdvancedStock\Block\StockMovement\Grid
{
```

It is working fine now.

There is a similar grid, which is showing in the edit form which is extending the same **`\BoostMyShop\AdvancedStock\Block\StockMovement\Grid`** class to show the same data for particular product.

Below is the sample code block for above class:

```
<?php

namespace BoostMyShop\AdvancedStock\Block\ErpProduct\Edit\Tab;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column;

class StockMovement extends \BoostMyShop\AdvancedStock\Block\StockMovement\Grid implements \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab\TabInterface
{
```

Now, the problem is that, since the **`StockMovement`** class extending from **`\BoostMyShop\AdvancedStock\Block\StockMovement\Grid`** class, my changes in the **`Stream\OverrideStockMovement\Block\Grid`** class are not being extended in this file.

If I use:

```
class StockMovement extends 
\Stream\OverrideStockMovement\Block\Grid implements \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab\TabInterface
```

instead of

```
class StockMovement extends \BoostMyShop\AdvancedStock\Block\StockMovement\Grid implements \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab\TabInterface
    {
```

My custom column is displayed in the grid, but I don't want to make changes in the extension's file.

I want to override the class with my own module's class file, so that I can make sure future upgrades of the extension are working fine.

**Edit:** I can't create plugin to extend the functionality, because the function, which I want to modify is a **`protected function`**.

Please help me, how can I do this?

Any help will be appreciated.